# Scripted Aggregation Calculation with unexpected results

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

First off I am somewhat new to ES / SK and even more so with aggrigations.

Here is my aggs structure:

```
  aggs: {
    all_budgets: {
      sum: {
        field: :amount
      }
    },
    all_forecasts: {
      sum: {
        field: :forecast_total
      }
    },
    all_variance: {
      sum: {
        script: "doc['forecast_total'].value - doc['amount'].value"
      }
    },
    all_variance_p: {
      sum: {
        script: "(doc['forecast_total'].value - doc['amount'].value) / doc['amount'].value"
      }
    }

  }
```

I am basically trying to get the total of all my budgets, total spent and then the over / under vs the budget and the corresponding %.  Here is my output:

```
{
  "all_forecasts": {
    "doc_count": 2,
    "value": 173604.0
  },
  "all_budgets": {
    "doc_count": 2,
    "value": 185437.0
  },
  "all_variance_p": {
    "doc_count": 2,
    "value": "0.33694326595832774"
  },
  "all_variance": {
    "doc_count": 2,
    "value": -11833.0
  }
}
```

The "0.33694326595832774" value is wrong - should be "-0.06408106257" (i.e. -11833.0 / 185437.0) .  The first two scripts work and I suspect I just don't understand how these scripts work.

Comment: Please add mapping and data

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your numbers to the same [datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html#number) before you divide. For instance `((float)(doc['forecast_total'].value) - (float)(doc['amount'].value)) / (float)(doc['amount'].value))`.

Comment: I know what the issue is - ES is calculating that `all_variance_p` for each document then summing them all. That's why `all_variance` works fine.  I need to access the final values of `all_budgets` and `all_forecasts` for the calculation.

Comment: Oh! Have a look at pipeline aggregations then. Those enable you to work with results of other aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comments to access final values of all_budgets and all_forecasts for further calculation, you can use [bucket script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) which can accessparent aggregation using bucket path. Since it requires buckets to work on , you will need to add a parent aggregation ex date_histogram which splits documents in given interval(year or month or date etc)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "year_interval": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "year"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "all_budgets": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        },
        "all_forecasts": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "forecast"
          }
        },
        "all_variance": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "total_forecast":"all_forecasts",
              "total_budget":"all_budgets"
            },
            "script": "params.total_forecast-params.total_budget"
          }
        },
        "all_variance_p": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "variance":"all_variance",
              "budget":"all_budgets"
            },
            "script": "params.variance/params.budget"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```